# Is is possible to calculate the MTBF or Failure rate from a given datasheet when manufacturer have not given these details?

Tags: reliability, component-failure, failure-analysis

As there are new components getting added to the mouser or digikey, is it possible to calculate the failure rate based on some pre known facts and values? some vendors don't reply for weeks and I can't wait that long for MTBF value.

Comment: MIL-HDBK-217F has typical MTBF for passives and types of IC's

Comment: I second that but only if the supplier has a decent reputation in the industry.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking anything more specific from the manufacturer, the best you can do in my opinion is to use MIL-217F.  You need to know something about the part you're interested in - for example is it bipolar, CMOS, SiGe; how many devices (gates); package type (plastic, ceramic, hybrid/MCM) number of pins/pads; the environment (lab, aircraft, space) and temperature range; duty cycle (some components are stressed more a turn-on), etc.

With that information in hand, you should be able get a very rough estimate of a part's expected lifetime.  Emphasis here is on the phrase "very rough".  If you're designing this into a high rel product, then the manufacturer needs to step up or you need to find a different manufacturer to work with - one that is used to dealing with the needs of customers designing hi-rel products.